# Create a user's link

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication

I have Created a website that have a login and signup form,
now what I need is to create a profile link for everyone who signup in PHP, Such as in twitter and Facebook.

How do I create a profile link for each user in PHP?

Comment: not getting , make it clear and precise  profile link? as profile page

Comment: yes as the profile page in facebook for example

Answer (score 1):

if login is successfull then store user id in session variable and excute the query  that will get the detail of the user from database and show the result... as simple as that and on any page if you want to get details of user use session variable and execute the query and display the result or you can do another thing as after login store user information in session and display details using sessions...i think this will help you if not fell free to ask again

Sample code

```
   <?php
    require_once('connection.php');
    $id=$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
    $result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member where mem_id='$id'");
    while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
    { 
    $fname=$row3['fname'];
    $lname=$row3['lname'];
    $address=$row3['address'];
    $contact=$row3['contact'];
    $picture=$row3['picture'];
    $gender=$row3['gender'];
    }
    ?>
<table width="398" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td height="26" colspan="2">Your Profile Information </td>
    <td><div align="right"><a href="index.php">logout</a></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="129" rowspan="5"><img src="<?php echo $picture ?>" width="129" height="129" alt="no image found"/></td>
    <td width="82" valign="top"><div align="left">FirstName:</div></td>
    <td width="165" valign="top"><?php echo $fname ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><div align="left">LastName:</div></td>
    <td valign="top"><?php echo $lname ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><div align="left">Gender:</div></td>
    <td valign="top"><?php echo $gender ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><div align="left">Address:</div></td>
    <td valign="top"><?php echo $address ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><div align="left">Contact No.: </div></td>
    <td valign="top"><?php echo $contact ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p align="center"><a href="index.php"></a></p>
```

Comment: That is great, but what I need exactly is creating a link as this link for example, http://www.thefacebook.us/profile.php?id=4 , 
when the user write id="any number" then go to the page and export the user data to the page as you did in the last code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a user id in your database for each user you could do something like this.

```
<a href="user_profile.php?id=1">User Profile</a>
```

Then get the id on user_profile.php using $_GET['id'].  Once you have this query the database on id and do what you want with the data.